# Download a file to my server directory using PHP

Tags: php, apache, server, download

my system uses a XML file generated by a URL and I need a script that every 30 minutes access that URL (https://www.shopfisio.com.br/feeds/teste-leo?download=true),  and download the file to my server directory.

Can somebody help me how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried to do? Any code samples?

Comment: you can run cron job for every 30 minutes

Answer (score 1):

In a simple case you can use following code:

```
<?php

    $xml = file_get_contents('https://www.shopfisio.com.br/feeds/teste-leo?download=true');
    file_put_contents('import.xml', $xml);
```

For scheduling execution of your script you might use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron job entry that run a script every 30 minutes. In the script you should use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), Or just use package like [guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle)  to create a request to the url and save the returning body into a file on your server by one of read&write like [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) files functions in php, hope thats help you.